# How to share test run data between pytests?

Tags: python, pytest

I would like to share the data and expected failure as well between different pytest test files. Let me give an example. I'm testing a class A in test_a.py and class B in test_b.py. Interestingly these two classes need to be compatible with each other so I want to test them on the same data and also mark some of the data as xfail. How can I do this?

example data:

```
my_test_data = [
     ('test_data', 'expected_output'),
     pytest.mark.xfail(('another_test', 'failing_output')),
]
```

I can put this in a `conftest.py` and import it from the tests but an explicit import does not feel right.

Answer (score 5):

I've fixed this by using params on a fixture which returns the testing data. If you put this into `conftest.py` file, you can use the fixture in the test files automatically. Here's an example:

```
# in conftest.py file
@pytest.fixture(params=my_test_data)
def my_test(request):
  return request.params
```

Having parameterized-data-returning fixture in `conftest.py` means you can use that data inside tests without importing it:

```
# in test files themselves
def test_whatever(my_test):
  # Do whatever you like with the test data
  print my_test[0]
```